# SQL Select grandparents

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a question for my sql course on selecting all the people that have grandchildren and list how many they have

```
    CREATE TABLE person (
  persID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  persFName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  persLName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  persDOB DATE,
  motherID INT,
  fatherID INT,
  persDOD DATE,
  persGender CHAR(1),

  PRIMARY KEY (persID)
);

CREATE TABLE couple (
  coupleID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  alphaSpouse INT NOT NULL,
  omegaSpouse INT NOT NULL,
  coupleStart DATE NOT NULL,
  coupleEnd DATE,

  PRIMARY KEY (coupleID),
  FOREIGN KEY (alphaSpouse) REFERENCES person(persID),
  FOREIGN KEY (omegaSpouse) REFERENCES person(persID)
);
```

and here is my query currently it is getting some data but not all of it and not sure where i went wrong :(

```
select (p.persFName+' '+p.persLName) as GrandParent, count(*) as Number_Of_Grandchildren --gets all the grandmothers
from person as p
join person as c on c.motherID=p.persID
join person as gm on gm.motherID=c.persID
where p.motherID is null
group by (p.persFName+' '+p.persLName)
union
select (p.persFName+' '+p.persLName) as GrandParent, count(*) as Number_Of_Grandchildren --gets all the grandfathers
from person as p
join person as d on d.fatherID=p.persID
join person as gf on gf.fatherID=d.persID
where p.fatherID is null
group by (p.persFName+' '+p.persLName);
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data and the results you get and what you expect to get?  It is much easier to pick out the problem when we can see data that causes the issue.

Comment: where p.motherID is null - this can be fishy. Can grandparent have parent?

Comment: The problem is that you are only finding maternal grandmothers and paternal grandfathers... You need to also pull in the mothers father and the fathers mother.

Comment: As @DanK pointed out: is your father's mother not your grandmother?  Instead of splitting this into 4 sections and using UNIONs, you should probably rework your join criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query only selects the mother's mother and father's father as grandparents.

Instead of having your query split into specific lineages (father's father, father's mother, etc), simply join using "if this person is the mother OR father":

```
from person as p
join person as  c on ( c.motherID = p.persID OR  c.fatherID = p.persID)
join person as gm on (gm.motherID = c.persID OR gm.fatherID = c.persID)
```

Note that the results may need to be deduped, especially if there's any "inbreeding" in these family trees.

Comment: Thank you so much!! didn't know i could join on a table with an or operator, learnt something new!

Comment: @therrienri - Any operators you can use in a WHERE clause can also be done in an ON clause (e.g. AND, OR, LIKE, ...).  Cheers!

Comment: The inbreeding problem can be resolved by doing `COUNT(DISTINCT gm.persID)`

Comment: @therrienri OR is perfectly valid in JOIN conditions, however in practice with large datasets (when reasonably applicable) you are often better off UNIONing similar queries as you did (but you needed to union 4 queries in this case...it would've been 8 for great-grandchildren, which gets "unreasonable") as OR pretty much destroys MySQL's ability to take advantage of INDEXing.

Comment: good to know! I thought as i was missing some cases in my union but the OR within a join for this is much cleaner and easier to understand for sure :)